# Can I get in when I'm already in the subway? Or go further, or go to the center?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

Would anyone help me with this:
If I'm already inside the coach of the subway, standing near the doors.  I think there are some passengers that will get off soon. What should I say to my friends to make way for the alighting passengers. Like

> 1. "lets go inside" or
> 2. "let's go further" or
> 3. "let's go to the center of the coach"

Wonder which sounds correct and normal. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps those are used in some regions, but as far as I know, they don't seem right.

"Let's go inside" doesn't quite make sense since you are already inside. (I think you are trying to say *let's go to the center*. Read below.)

"Let's go further" could make sense if you're already moving towards a particular section. As an initial command, it doesn't make sense.

"Let's go to the center of the coach" could work if standing in the "center" doesn't block exiting passengers.

I would say

> 1. Let's step/move aside.
> 2. Let's get/move out of the way.
> 3. Let's go/move to the [location].
> 4. Let's go/move further to the [location].

where the [location] is a place that does not block the exiting passengers, like the back/front/center/etc. You can use 4 when your initial movement was insufficient. *To the [location]* is optional in 4, since the location should be clear from context.

Comment: Thanks. Would "go along" make any sense at all? @Max

Comment: At the moment, I think *no*, if you're trying to avoid them. If you are trying to follow the crowd, then yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Also, please [wait longer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting an answer. We like to prevent users from accepting answers so quickly. :)

Comment: ok! i will consider waiting longer next time!